# New in Baking. From High to Low mesh

Tags: modeling, workflow, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I have followed several tutorials on baking normals onto a low poly mesh.

This is my High Mesh:
[image]
[image]

This is my Low Mesh:
[image]
[image]

I am also using a Cage encompassing both the low and high poly mesh:

[image]
I turned on both meshes (low and high) to share how they overlap:

[image]
[image]

This is the baked resul, bake created with the normal map disconnected and low poly mesh in smooth shading.

[image]
[image]

Properties, Max Ray half of the longest axis of my mesh:
[image]

I can see some things look a bit off:

1. The Normal Map colour seems wrong; watching some videos, they describe the normal map as more saturated. I followed the creation of the image texture as the instructor described, doing it at 4k and 32 bits, then specifying that the colour space should be "non-colour" in the properties panel of the image space.
2. the broken normal coincides with the areas (overlapped image shared before) not covered by the low poly mesh concerning the high poly.
3. I am not sure if the Max Distance is rightly set. I also realized the scale is applied, but the mesh is too big regarding how many meters I use; I am unsure if this affects the process.

I would highly appreciate some guidance if you have experience doing this and find something to pinpoint on the shared images.

Thank you

Comment: You don't show your low poly without the normals already connected. You don't mention the low poly is smooth shaded. So that would be my first advice: upon baking disconnect the normals texture from the low poly material, **shade it smooth** and make sure you bake onto the texture (easiest to create a new black texture, so if it changes the bake actually happened), set max ray distance to about half of the width of the object, so you don't hit the wrong side, thanks to which you will see where the rays miss and so will be able to play with extrusion level or cage...

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure to understand, your high and low-poly seem to have a rather similar shape, so what kind of detail are you trying to bake?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Hi. I am not sure If I get the first part of your reply. I did show the low poly mesh with the normal map connected. The normals were created with the normal map disconnected; Blender does give you a notification when you do not disconnect about dependencies. I did not know I needed to smooth shade it. That is a great tip. 
Do you refer to the shortest side with the width? 
Thank you. I will come back with your suggestions, but I am afraid there is no way to post images in the comments.

Comment: @moonboots You are completely right, and after posting, I kept reading my post, and realized that the original mesh (high) was missing the details. So great to pinpoint, the mesh I shared was actually not the one to intervine.

Comment: Updated the post with newest attempts.

Comment: *"Do you refer to the shortest side with the width?"* - can work. Basically, it doesn't matter, but if you make it short enough not to be able to hit the other side, you will find more easily the misses in the normal. Also very suspicious is complete lack of detail here: https://i.imgur.com/zAYdIGE.png - as if you baked from low poly to high poly by accident… If it's your first time baking, I highly recommend testing on something easier first, without a cage. Also if you share your .blend file, it will be easier for us to help: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Can I send it to you privately?

Comment: @BrunoSuraski if you're unwilling to share it, then one reason for me not to answer is not to risk revealing something you want to hide. See here on how to remove sensitive data from .blend file: [How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3050/60486)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I am not unwilling to share; If I were, I would not be asking you to send it privately. But that does not mean I want to share with the entire google database.

Comment: you can use another platform like wetransfer or workupload

Comment: Would you be able to check it if I send you the link? Thank you